# The z-index of SwiftUI View and UIKit View

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swiftui, z-index

**The SwiftUI scroll view is hiding some area of a view presented from UIViewControllerRepresentable viewController.**

[image]

Part of the SwiftUI code, The GoogleMapsView is the UIViewControllerRepresentable viewController.

```
struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {

        GoogleMapsView()

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Top Locations near you")

            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack() {
                    ForEach(dataSource.topPlaces) { place in
                        PlaceCardView(placeImage: place.image, placeName: place.name, placeRating: place.rating, placeRatingTotal: place.ratingTotal, topPlace: place)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 10)
            }
            .background(Color.clear)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(height: 200)
            .opacity(self.finishedFetching ? 1 : 0.1)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.3))           
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

The view I want to put on the top is from the GoogleMapView() which I put it on the "bottom" of the ZStack because I want that Scroll view to flow on the map. However the view show on the map when marker is tapped is cover up by the SwiftUI ScrollView

I tried to change their zIndex of the scrollView, zPosition of the pop up view or bringSubviewToFront etc. None of them work.

Comment: zIndex works only for views in one container, so you need either hide top scrollview when show popup view, or extract popup view from GoogleMapsView and show it in same ZStack above all.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your reply, I got your point. If I want to hide the top scrollview when showing the pop up view, how to hide it when a func is called in the GoogleMaps viewController? I just tried by using a global variable but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject local state via binding into `` and change it there on popup shown/hidden.

Here is some pseudo code

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var isPopup = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .top) {

        GoogleMapsView(isPopup: $isPopup)

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Top Locations near you")

            if !isPopup {
               ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                  // other code
               }
               // other code
            }
    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}

struct GoogleMapsView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   @Binding isPopup: Bool

   // other code

   // make self.isPopup = true before popup and false after
```